# Elle vend un ancien chapeau - meaning of "ancien"

Tags: adjectifs, ordre-des-mots

I have read the following sentence in a [French language learning tool](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/7669006):

> Elle vend un ancien chapeau.

According to https://about-france.com/french/adjectives.htm, the adjective "ancien" means "former" when it precedes a noun and "ancient" / "old" when it comes after it. Larousse examples in the [definition](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ancien/3330) of the adjective "ancien" seem to confirm it. As "a former hat" makes no sense, is the sentence above incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Former hat" is not idiomatic but "hat she used to wear" is, and that is what "ancien chapeau" means. It remains to find a word or at least a shorter combination of English words to express that, if possible. I know of none that should be unambiguous. "Previous hat" is not better than "former hat".

You can say "old" in English though, as in "my old school"; it means "former" as you'll probably recall, but if "former" is not idiomatic for "hat", I think that "old" is ([OALD, number 5](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/old?q=old)).

- She is selling an old hat of hers.